# Showing that $\text{Ind}_H^G(\text{Res}_H^G \rho \otimes \sigma) \simeq \rho \otimes \text{Ind}_H^G \sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm stuck on this problem about representations of finite group:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \subseteq G$ a subgroup. Let also $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be two representations of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Show that:
> $$\text{Ind}_H^G(\text{Res}_H^G \rho \otimes \sigma) \simeq \rho \otimes \text{Ind}_H^G \sigma.$$

I tried to show that $\rho \otimes \text{Ind}_H^G \sigma$ satisfies the universal property of the induced representation for $\text{Res}_H^G \rho \otimes \sigma$, and I showed that this is equivalent to the fact that for every $\tau$ representation of $G$ any $f:V_\rho \times V_\sigma \to V_\tau$ bilinear $H$-equivariant form extends uniquely to some $g:V_\rho \times V_{\text{Ind}_H^G \sigma} \to V_\tau$ bilinear $G$-equivariant form. I can define this $g$ only on $V_\rho \times \iota(V_\sigma)$ (where $\iota$ is the immersion of $V_\sigma \to V_{\text{Ind}_H^G \sigma}$) but I'm not able to extend this to the whole space.

**edit:** with $H$-equivariant I mean that for every $h \in H$ $f(\rho(h)v, \sigma(h)w) = \tau(h) f(v,w)$, this means that in the tensor product the corresponding $\bar{f} \in \text{Hom}_H(\rho \otimes \sigma, \tau)$. Same definition for $G$-equivariant.

Does this approach work? Is there maybe a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove that their decomposition to a direct sum of irreducible representations is the same. Let $\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_n$ be the irreducible representations of $G$. We know that the multiplicity of an irreducible representation $\rho_i$ in a rep. $\rho$ is given by: $$\langle \rho,\rho_i\rangle$$ And we also have Frobenius reciprocity:
$$\langle Ind_H^G \psi,\varphi\rangle_G=\langle \psi,Res^G_H\varphi\rangle_H$$ with $\psi$ a rep. of $H$ and $\varphi$ a rep of $G$. Therefore: $$\langle \text{Ind}_H^G(\text{Res}_H^G \rho \otimes \sigma),\rho_i\rangle=\langle Res_H^G\rho\otimes\sigma,Res^G_H\rho_i\rangle=\langle\sigma,Res_H^G\rho^*\otimes Res_H^G\rho_i\rangle=\langle\sigma,Res_H^G(\rho^*\otimes\rho_i)\rangle=$$$$=\langle Ind_H^G\sigma,\rho^*\otimes\rho_i\rangle=\langle Ind_H^G\sigma\otimes\rho,\rho_i\rangle$$
As this is true for all $1\leq i\leq n$, they have the same decomposition to irreducible representations and hence: $$\text{Ind}_H^G(\text{Res}_H^G \rho \otimes \sigma)\cong Ind_H^G \sigma\otimes\rho\cong\rho\otimes Ind_H^G\sigma$$

That is the simplest solution I know, and in most cases that is all you need to prove such claims.

Comment: This proof can also be used when $G$ is not finite but say $GL_n(F)$ if we know $\rho$ is irreducible right?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Ind}{\operatorname{Ind}}\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}$One can write down the isomorphisms explicitly as follows:

For concreteness, we identify $\Ind_H^G\sigma$ with $\mathbb C[G]\otimes_{\mathbb C[H]}\sigma$ (where $G$ is only acting on the left factor). In order to not have to write too many tensor products, I abbreviate $[g,v] := g\otimes v$. Then we have the following properties:

1. $[g,v]$ is $\mathbb C$-linear in $v$ and every element of $\Ind_H^G\sigma$ is a $\mathbb C$-linear combination of the $[g,v]$'s for varying $g\in G$, $v\in V_\sigma$;
2. $[gh,v] = [g,\sigma(h)v]$ for all $g\in G$, $h\in H$, $v\in V_\sigma$;
3. $\gamma\cdot [g,v] = [\gamma g,v]$ for all $\gamma,g\in G$, $v\in V_\sigma$.

Note that we have a canonical $H$-equivariant map
$$
\begin{align*}
\Res^G_H\rho \otimes \sigma &\longrightarrow \Res^G_H(\rho\otimes \Ind_H^G\sigma) = \Res^G_H\rho \otimes \Res^G_H\Ind_H^G\sigma,\\
v\otimes w &\longmapsto v\otimes [1,w].
\end{align*}
$$
By Frobenius reciprocity, we obtain a $G$-equivariant map
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi\colon \Ind_H^G(\Res^G_H\rho\otimes \sigma) &\longrightarrow \rho\otimes \Ind_H^G\sigma,\\
[g, v\otimes w] &\longmapsto \rho(g)v\otimes [g,w].
\end{align*}
$$
The inverse map is given explicitly by
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi\colon \rho\otimes \Ind_H^G\sigma &\longrightarrow \Ind_H^G(\Res^G_H\rho \otimes \sigma),\\
v\otimes [g,w] &\longmapsto [g,\rho(g^{-1})v\otimes w].
\end{align*}
$$
I leave it to you to check that $\psi$ is well-defined, $G$-equivariant, and the inverse of $\varphi$.